# What is the value of the angle $x$ in the figure below?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

For reference: If ABCD is a symmetric trapezoid, (AB = BC); M, N, L, F and P are midpoints of AB, BC, CD, AD and BD respectively. Calculate x (answer $36^\circ$)

[image]

My progress:

Symmetric trapezoids are those that have sides congruent 2 to two

IF AB = BC then AD=DC

MNFL is rectangle

$ K = ML\cap NF \\Draw~ MN \parallel FL\\\triangle FKL \cong\triangle MKN $

but I think it needs to demonstrate that the distance from HI = PG...

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like a trapezoid to me... Did you get the diagram right? (Or the problem?)

Comment: That's a [kite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite_(geometry)) not a [trapezoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid). Hint: $MPLI$ is a parallelogram.

Comment: @TheBestMagician In Peruvian geometry it is considered a symmetrical trapezoid. see the
the image I posted

Comment: @dxiv In Peruvian geometry it is considered a symmetrical trapezoid. see the
the image I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In triangle BNI, H is midpoint of BI. PL connects the midpoints of DB and DC so it is parallel with BN. Also HN||GL and HN=GL, in this way $\triangle 
 BHN=\triangle BGL$ therefore $GP=HB=HI$. Also trapezoid PLNI is isosceles and extension of sides NI and PL intersect at a point like R such that triangle RNL is isosceles and  RN is perpendicular bisector of NL so it is the axis of symmetry of trapezoid. Hence NI and PL are mirrors about RN or are symmetric of each other which results in $x=36^o$

Comment: grateful as always

Answer (score 1):

Since $GD$ and $IH$ are midle lines with respect to $AC'$ we have $GD = IH$ and $GD||IH$ so $IHGD$ is paralelogram. So $\angle IHG = \angle HGD$. Now $E$ and $F$ are reflection points of $G$ and $H$ with respect to $AB$ so $\angle DEF = \angle HGD$ and thus a conclusion.

[image]

Comment: great resolution... grateful

Comment: fell free to upvote